# Unable to init vscode-neovim: command 'type' already exists

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Here is the error I get:

```
Unable to init vscode-neovim: command 'type' already exists
```

[image: Error Screenshot]

Strangely, everything seems to work fine when working with the extension though. I'm using MacOS Big Sur 11.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, according to [this comment](https://github.com/vscode-neovim/vscode-neovim/issues/368#issuecomment-696677159) — and I can confirm it does work on my end —, this might be a conflict with the [Vim (vscodevim)](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscodevim.vim) extension. Just disable it, reload VS Code and the error disappears.

> This is also stated [here](https://github.com/vscode-neovim/vscode-neovim#troubleshooting) in the extension's own documentation.